# Most efficient way to encrypt files?

Tags: encryption, 7zip

So I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model 2 with an external HDD attached to it. I wonder which is the most efficient way to encrypt large files (~10GB).

I have been using 7zip to add the files to a password-protected archive with no compression and to split them in smaller parts:

```
7z a -p filename -mx0 -v100m -mhe file-to-be-encrypted
```

However it lasts ages for a 10GB file to be processed due to the high load on the CPU.

So maybe there is a simpler way to encrypt the files that doesn't require so much CPU power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openSSL which is safe and highly secure.
For large files (over 600 MB) you'll have to split your file into small ones with `split` command

```
split -b 500M -d -a 4 <large_file> large_file.part.
```

then use `openssl smime` to encrypt each piece

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'large_file.part.*' | sort | xargs -I % openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes-256-cbc -in % -out %.enc -outform DER PUBLIC_PEM_FILE
```

To decrypt the file , you'll have to redo in reverse order

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'large_file.part.*.enc' | sort | xargs -I % openssl smime -decrypt -in % -binary -inform DEM -inkey PRIVATE_PEM_FILE -out %.dec
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'large_file.part.*.dec' | sort | xargs cat > restored_large_file
```

Answer (score 1):

`ccrypt` is a pretty decent way of quickly scrambling a file (or files).

It's in the repositories, so just install with:

```
sudo apt-get install ccrypt
```

It comes with a handy variation of `cat`, called `ccat`. If you encrypt a text file with `ccrypt` you can use `ccat` to quickly display it in the terminal.

`ccrypt` isn't just for text files though. You can use it on any files.